# Fine-grained object model in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, database-design, persistence, hibernate-mapping, object-persistence

In the Hibernate in Action (Manning publication),

> A major objective of the Hibernate project is support for fine-grained object models, which we isolated as the most important requirement for rich domain model. In crude term, fine-grained means "more classes than table".

I don't get this... Please some body help on this.

Answer (score 1):

This refers (I think) to what Hibernate calls ["components"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html), and what JPA calls "embedded classes".  See the link for an explanation of what that means.

Comment: Thanks skaffman, but, what's the point of doing that? Ultimately, hoe do we persist the grained object? To the same table? [More classes than tables] If so, then what is the purpose of that? I don't get it.

Comment: @abimaran: The component objects are automatically "inlined" into the big table by Hibernate. It allows you to have a nice fine-grained object model without having fine-grained tables.

Comment: For example, if we have a Person class, then there are attributes for address like, home_Location, home_City, home_Country. But, with the concept of fine-grained object, we can model it as Person class and Address class instead the person class directly have all those home_Location, home_City, home_Country address directly. But, ultimately those will be persisted to the same table. So what is the advantages of the fine-grained objects?

Comment: @abimaran: Well that's subjective, but a fine-grained object model is generally nicer to work with